# Exploding nested df columns in Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Column name is 'col1' and is of the form:

```
col1: array (nullable = true)
|     |-- A1: struct (containsNull = true)
|     |       |-- B0: struct (nullable = true)
|     |       |    |-- B01: string (nullable = true)
|     |       |    |-- B02: string (nullable = true)
|     |       |-- B1: string (nullable = true)
|     |       |-- B2: string (nullable = true)
|     |       |-- B3: string (nullable = true)
|     |       |-- B4: string (nullable = true)
|     |       |-- B5: string (nullable = true)
```

I am trying 2 things first to fetch the value B2. Code:

```
val explodeDF = test_df.explode($"col1") { case Row(col1_details:Array[String]) => 
  col1_details:Array.map{ col1_details:Array =>
    val firstName = col1_details:Array(2).asInstanceOf[String]
    val lastName = col1_details:Array(3).asInstanceOf[String]
    val email = col1_details:Array(4).asInstanceOf[String]
    val salary = col1_details:Array(5).asInstanceOf[String]
    notes_details(firstName, lastName, email, salary)
  }
}
```

Error:

```
error: too many arguments for method apply: (index: Int)Char in class StringOps
     col1_details(firstName, lastName, email, salary)
```

I have tried various snippets and I have been getting different errors. Any suggestions on the what the mistake would be highly helpful.

Comment: what are two things you are trying ? you just mentioned one. And can you explain what are col1_details and notes_details?

Comment: You should be more specific on what you mean by "fetch the value B2". Do you simply want a Dataset that contains B2? Unique?